# how to put a scrollbar selector in bootstrap slider carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slider, scrollbar, carousel

I want to handle slides with a scrollbar instead of arrows or indicators. How can I do that??

[Click here to view the image example](http://inmotioncreative.net/dev/autonica/img/slider.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a similar thing. Didn't quite find anything related to Bootstrap, but got this(Swiper) slider instead which does the job pretty well. 
I hope it helps.

EDIT:

- First download Swiper slider from [here](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper).
- Then download the scrollbar plugin for the slider from [here](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper-Scrollbar).
- Follow the instructions given in its readme.

Comment: Please add relevant parts of the linked source as part of your answer.